# Add php define variable in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php varaiable that I need to pass into a link in a javascript function

```
//In the config
<?php
    define('THE_VAR', 'test');
?>


//On the page
<?php
    $the_var = THE_VAR;
?>

<script>
    (function()){
        link = "test.site"+<?php echo json_encode($the_var); ?>+"/testing.js"
    })();
</script>
```

I need the link in the javascript function to read.

```
test.site/test/testing.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of: `link = "test.site"+<?php echo json_encode($the_var); ?>+"/testing.js"`

Use: `link = "test.site/<?= $the_var; ?>/testing.js";`

Comment: that just outputs "test.site/'+"test"+'/testing.js";

Comment: True, I made a mistake! Try it now, I edited my post.

Answer (score -1):

Use Ajax for passing the data from php into the javascript.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp